# How can I use MapFallbackToFile in Asp.Net Core?

Tags: asp.net-core

I can install a fallback route with a string

```
app.MapFallback(() => "some text");
```

but if I replace this with

```
app.MapFallbackToFile("text.txt"); // works neither relative 
app.MapFallbackToFile("c:\\folder\\text.txt"); // nor with full path
```

I receive HTTP 404. How does MapFallbackToFile work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to place `text.txt` file inside `wwwroot` folder and also add the `UseStaticFiles` middleware.

```cs
app.UseStaticFiles();

...

app.MapFallbackToFile("text.txt");
```

Comment: I already used UseStaticFiles but MapFallbackToFile only works with "wwwroot".